# How should I translate "for" in this sentence?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

> This room is for talking about Latin[.SE].

Now, I've got most of this translated. The only thing I'm stumbling on is how to translate "for". I see two options, but neither is very good:

- "pro" -- It means "on behalf of", so I could twist it into "on behalf of the couple's happiness", but from the other meanings given I think it has a different connotation, and doesn't fit right.
- An *ut* clause of purpose -- It seems to fit, until you realize that it's basically saying "let us drink so that the couple will have a happy marriage" -- I'm sure they could have a happy one without that toast, especially if they were both oblivious like me.
- ad + gerund(ive) -- same as above.

Am I missing something about these options? Is there another that would fit better?

*NB: I'm leaving out the .SE part intentionally.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to translate "for" alone, so let me give you more complete expressions.
A couple of options come to mind:

- Hoc conclave situi (interretiali) Latin.SE disputando dedicatum est.
- Hic de situ Latin.SE colloqui licet.
- Ut de situ Latin.SE colloquamur. (So that we may talk about the site. This is incomplete but a beginning like "Hoc conclave creatum est" can be understood implicitly.)
- Hoc conclave dedicatum est colloquiis de situ Latin.SE.

These are not literal, but may confer the meaning clearly enough.
If you just want a (sub)title for a chat room, then a dative expression like "[conclave] situi Latin.SE disputando" or "[conclave] disputationibus de situ Latin.SE" would work well.
A similar dative construction with a gerundive can be found in the name of [*Academia Latinitati Fovendae*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academia_Latinitati_Fovendae).

If you want to talk about Latin as a language instead of Latin.SE as a website, simply substitute *Lingua latina* for my *situs Latin.SE*.

My exact recommendation depends on where you want to use that phrase.
I can update if you give more details.
It often is difficult to translate compact expressions properly without context.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm. I'd actually suggest the gerundive: *ad Latinam disputandam* or *Latinæ disputandæ causa*. [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/GerundGerundive.pdf) puts it nicely:

> The Gerundive (like the Gerund) may be used with ad + acc. or gen. + causa to express purpose. This is the regular construction where a Direct Object is involved.

That said, @Joonas Ilmavirta's suggestions, though they show less characteristically Roman brevity, all work very well, too.

Comment: Perfect! There's one thing missing, though...(hint: it ends on *-pices*).

Comment: Spices? Auspices? Precipices? Haruspices? :)